# How to continue code to allow me to click on image and display a separate page with more info

Tags: javascript, php

As of right now, I am able to display my images in a single column, with an image, a title, and a small description. All of this is derived from the same database. I am not very good at coding and need some guidance, how would you add onto this existing code to 1) allow the pictures to be displayed in more than one column...and 2)allow the thumbnails to be clicked on, which will load a separate page that I can then style and list the full recipe on.

I have been messing with the code in general, and I am confused by what I created. I am not sure how to proceed.

```
<h2>index.php:</h2>
<section class="gallery-links">
    <div class="wrapper">


        <div class="gallery-container">
            <?php

            include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY orderGallery DESC"
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo "SQL statment failed!";
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                        echo '<a href="#">
                        <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].');"></div>
                        <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
                        <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
                    </a>';
                    }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php
        echo '<div class="gallery-upload">
            <form action="includes/gallery-upload.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="filename" placeholder="File name...">
                <input type="text" name="filetitle" placeholder="Image title...">
                <input type="text" name="filedesc" placeholder="Image description...">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        </div>'
        ?>

    </div>
</section>

<h2>gallery-upload.inc.php:</h2>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$newFileName = $_POST['filename'];
if (empty($newFileName)) {
    $newFileName = "gallery";
} else {
$newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $newFileName));
}
$imageTitle = $_POST['filetitle'];
$imageDesc = $_POST['filedesc'];

$file = $_FILES["file"];

$fileName = $file["name"];
$fileType = $file["type"];
$fileTempName = $file["tmp_name"];
$fileError = $file["error"];
$fileSize = $file["size"];

$fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
if ($fileError === 0) {
    if($fileSize < 2000000) {
        $imageFullName = $newFileName . "." . uniqid("", true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
        $fileDestination = "../images/gallery/" . $imageFullName;

        include_once "dbh.inc.php";

        if (empty($imageTitle) || empty($imageDesc)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?upload=empty");
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery;";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                echo "SQL statement failed!";
            } else {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                $setImageOrder = $rowCount + 1;

                $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (titleGallery, descGallery, imgFullNameGallery, orderGallery) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    echo "SQL statement failed!";
                } else {
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $imageTitle, $imageDesc, $imageFullName, $setImageOrder);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                    move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);

                    header("Location: ../index.php?upload=success");
                }
            }
        }

    } else {
        echo "File size is too big!";
        exit();
    }
} else {
    echo "You had an error!";
    exit();
}
} else {
  echo "You need to upload a proper file type!";
  exit();
}

<h2>dbh.inc.php:</h2>
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "gallery";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you need to make a link on `anchor` tag which will have `url` of image detailed page with `image id` as below:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // assuming that imgId is your primary key 
        echo '<a href="detail.php?imageId="'.$row["imgId"].' target="_blank">
            <div style="background-image: url(img/gallery/'.$row["imgFullNameGallery"].');"></div>
            <h3>'.$row["titleGallery"].'</h3>
            <p>'.$row["descGallery"].'</p>
        </a>';
    }
```

After, you need to create a new file `detail.php` where you can get `image id` by `$_GET['imgId']` and then can query on that and will be able to get complete image details. You will also need to create a `HTML` for view and can show details.

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: My primary key is idGallery i believe. So i basically replace my anchor statement with yours. Then, in a new file, use $_GET['idGallery ']. This provides me with all the info associated with that Id, and then I can create an html/css file from there?

Comment: Yes, replace your anchor tag with mine and also use idGallery instead of imgId from my anchor tag syntax.

Comment: ok appreciate it. Any advice for updating my CSS? As of right now the images display in a single column. Do you know how I could update it so they display in 3-4 columns?

Comment: You can use bootstrap for CSS. Please check this free theme which can provide great fetaures: https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html. You can freely download this and can customize your page as you want :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help! One last question, how would you go about querying this? I have never done this before and querying is by far my weakest skill. You probably need to see my database, I am just very lost.

Comment: Same as you have already done that in your code. include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';  $sql = "SELECT * FROM gallery where idGallery = '".$_GET['idGallery']."' ORDER BY orderGallery DESC"; $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);